# jQuery order li with the value under ul with the same id value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to order the list of elements with the specific `data-value` under the  tag with the same `id` value. All `<li>` tags with `data-value="742"` should append to `<ul id="742" class="fieldrow">`

```
<div class="result">
   <p></p>
   <h2>The list of libraries:</h2>
   <p></p>
   <li class="fieldrow" data-value="742">North Olmsted Branch (742)</li>
   <li class="fieldrow" data-value="7143">Birch Primary School (QuickStart) (7143)</li>
   <li class="fieldrow" data-value="2060">Westlake Porter Public Library (2060)</li>
   <li class="fieldrow" data-value="6223">Westlake High School (6223)</li>
   <li class="fieldrow" data-value="742">Fairview Park Branch (742)</li>
   <li class="fieldrow" data-value="742">Olmsted Falls Branch (742)</li>
   <li class="fieldrow" data-value="6520">North Ridgeville City Schools (6520)</li>
   <li class="fieldrow" data-value="742">Berea Branch (742)</li>
   <li class="fieldrow" data-value="5435">Rocky River High School (5435)</li>
   <li class="fieldrow" data-value="742">Bay Village Branch (742)</li>
   <hr>
   <ul id="742" class="fieldrow">Cuyahoga County Public Library</ul>
   <ul id="2060" class="fieldrow">Westlake Porter Public Library</ul>
   <ul id="5435" class="fieldrow">Rocky River High School</ul>
   <ul id="6223" class="fieldrow">Westlake High School</ul>
   <ul id="6520" class="fieldrow">North Ridgeville City Schools</ul>
   <ul id="7143" class="fieldrow">Birch Primary School (QuickStart)</ul>
</div>
<script>
$(".result ul").each(function () {    //loop over each list item
    datas= $(this).attr('id');   
    $(".result li data-value['"+datas+"']").appendTo(".result ul data-value['"+datas+"']);

});</script>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/301ppm78/2/)

Comment: Your HTML is really invalid. `<li>`s need a `<ul>` as their parent. And a `<ul>` can also only have a `<li>` as its child.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Minor update

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmvw2fop/1/).

```
$(".result li[data-value='"+id+"']").each(function () {
    var id =  $(this).data('value');   
    $(".result ul#" + id).append($(this));
});
```

Comment: not like that, the other way. Well, in that case I can just switch it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are appending the parent list to the child list item and you dont need to wrap `this`, append/appendTo accept DOM elements

Comment: Updated so the LI's are being appended to ULs

Comment: You dont need to use the attribute-selector for ID, either. You can just use `".result ul#" + id`

Comment: Thanks, that is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems in your demo.

The first is that you are missing a quote at the end of your second selector (inside of the `appendTo` call.)

Next your selectors are incorrect. When selecting an attribute in jQuery you need to use `[attr='val']`, not `attr['val']`.

Finally you are trying to grab the relevant unordered list by the `data-value` attribute but the unordered lists do not have that attribute, they use the ID.

jQuerys `.each` sets the current context as the DOM element it is iterating over. This means that your `this` variable inside of the each is one of `.result ul`. `append`/`appendTo` accept a DOM element directly so you can just `appendTo` `this` to append the selected list items to the current list.

With these changes you are left with

```
$(".result ul").each(function () {    //loop over each list item
    var datas= $(this).attr('id');   
    $(".result li[data-value='"+datas+"']").appendTo(this);
});
```

As a side note, you don't really need to wrap `this` as a jQuery object for the ID, either. DOM objects expose the ID directly by property.

So instead of

```
var datas= $(this).attr('id');
```

You can do

```
this.id
```

If you include this you can trim your code down to

```
$(".result ul").each(function () {    //loop over each list item  
    $(".result li[data-value='" + this.id + "']").appendTo(this);
});
```